# Correct way to Calculate total Profit/Loss of an account in mql4?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, mql, metatrader5

I am trying to calculate total Profit/Loss of the account but everything I have tried so far has only resulted in failure

its a demo account with deposit : 100K
Profit/Loss : (negative)-31009.63
No active trade

Here is what I have attempted till now :

```
AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_PROFIT); 

//it returned 0.0
```

Then I tried calculating Profit/Loss of all historic trades like this :

```
   double tempproloss = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<OrdersHistoryTotal(); i++)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY))
        {
         if(OrderType()<=5)
           {
            tempproloss =  tempproloss+OrderProfit();

           }
        }
     }
//This returned -6188.09 which is still not correct
```

Then I tried calculating Profit/Loss Of all orders including deposits etc , like this :

```
double tempproloss = 0;
for(int i=0;i<OrdersHistoryTotal();i++)
  {
   if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY))
     {
           tempproloss =  tempproloss+OrderProfit();
     }
  } 

//It returned 29406.49 , no idea how it ended up with this number.
```

Then I got the Deposit value in a variable and then I tried Calculating Profit/Loss of all closed trades (Not including the deposit etc) and then Subtracted it from Deposit amount , like this :

```
double Deposits = 0;
for(int i=0;i<OrdersHistoryTotal();i++)
  {
   if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY))
     {
      if(OrderType() == 6)
        {
        if(OrderProfit()>0)
          {
           Deposits =  Deposits+OrderProfit();
          }
        
        }
     }
  }   
double tempproloss = 0;
for(int i=0;i<OrdersHistoryTotal();i++)
  {
   if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY))
     {
     if(OrderType()<6)
       {
           tempproloss =  tempproloss+OrderProfit();
       }
     }
  }  
 Print( Deposits -tempproloss );

// it Returned 106188.09 which wrong again
```

Been struggling with this for quite some time, but couldn't figure out a way to make it work , can someone please point out What am I missing ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Account History tab, right-click and select All History. Run your scripts again.

If the above gets you closer, include OrderCommission() and OrderSwap() if you need the exact PnL value.

> AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_PROFIT);
>
> //it returned 0.0

This only shows profit for open orders.

Answer (score 0):

this code is working

```
void totalTp(){
    tp = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < OrdersTotal(); i++){
    if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
    {      
        if(OrderType()==OP_BUY || OrderType() == OP_SELL )
        {             
          tp += OrderProfit();        
        }
    }}
    Comment(tp);
}
```